# Possible to prevent direct import in Java?

Tags: java, class, import, static

Due to the structure of our objects, we may have multiple cases where a subclass has the same name of another subclass in a different parent.

In IDE typeahead, typing the name of a class will often lead to the IDE helpfully adding the import dynamically.

However, if multiple subclasses with that name exist, it's all too easy for the wrong one to be imported.

So, the goal here is for a way to design the subclass in such a way that it could only be referenced via its parent class.

For example let's say:

```
public static class PageOne {
    public static class HeaderSection {
        String foo;
    }
}
public static class PageTwo {
    public static class HeaderSection {
        String foo;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to prevent someone from simply referencing `HeaderSection.foo` and instead require that they have to reference e.g. `PageOne.HeaderSection.foo`. In other words make it invalid to import `PageOne.HeaderSection` but only valid to import `PageOne`.

(Or is this simply not possible?)

Comment: Why are these subclasses public? It is not at all clear why you have chosen this design, but there is no magic don't allow users to import this public class. Also, why even have two identical subclasses? It seems like `HeaderSection` should be an interface, but I'm still scratching my head wondering why you have done / want this.

Comment: *"Or is this simply not possible?"* --- It is not possible.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch they are basically hierarchically nested structs. They are public to allow direct reference. But there are times where I might want their reference to be qualified, to avoid ambiguous references which could cause headaches. That was the goal here. If someone imports both PageOne.HeaderSection and PageTwo.HeaderSection and they then use HeaderSection.foo expecting to get PageTwo.HeaderSection.foo and instead get PageOne.HeaderSection.foo, then they will be barking up trees. And I really want to avoid PageOne.PageOneHeaderSection type naming.

Comment: *They are public to allow direct reference.* There is your problem. **Never** allow direct reference. That breaks encapsulation in and of itself. Also, they are not nested structs. Because Java does not have structs. Don't try and write C/C++ in Java.